# Showing answers by votes not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1509785?sort=votes#sort-top) (probably others too), if I try to sort the answers by 'Votes' its still showing an answer with 2 votes above an answer with 3 votes. Please see the screenshot [here](http://i34.tinypic.com/2n07mf6.png).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The accepted answer is always first.

Comment: Not always.  Self-accepted answers remain in place.  But that is what's happening in this case.

Comment: It's just that now it's hard to see whether an answer is accepted.

Comment: See. this is why they need to bring back the accepted answer's green color, its too easy to miss that the answer is accepted right now